# Unable to Start an Azure VM using Powershell script. We get Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-vm-role

We use powershell script to start and stop the VMs using the build job. Please see the screenshot of the build job below

[image]

It is a simple powershell script to start an VM. The issue is when this job runs, we are getting an error and the build fails.
We get **Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters**

But when we run it locally using the powershell console, the VMs get started.

Please find the error screenshot below

[image]

Am I missing something here.. Any help would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT 1**
Powershell script

```
$machines = @("machinename")
Select-AzureSubscription -Default "XXXYYYZZZ"

Foreach ($machine in $machines)
{   
Try
{
    Start-AzureVM -ServiceName $machine -Name $machine
}
Catch
{
}
}
```

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - Thanks. Have added the script.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT - I feel this is not a script issue as the script works fine standalone.

Comment: I notice that when you execute your cmdlet local, you logon Azure using `Add-AzureRmAccount` and select subscription with `select-azurermsubscription`, they are ARM mode cmdlet.

Comment: `Select-AzureSubscription -Default "XXXYYYZZZ"` The cmdlet could execute successful on your local PC? I test in my lab, I get same error with you on build.

Comment: You could not add parameters after `Default`.

Comment: I've answered the cause of this issue extensively here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57066620/is-there-something-i-am-fundamentally-missing-from-this-powershell-script-i-am-r?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check your screenshot, I find you want to stop classic VMs. However, you logon Azure with cmdlet `Add-AzureRmAccount` and select subscription with cmdlet `select-azurermsubscription`, am I right? The two cmdlets are ARM mode cmdlets, you should use classic mode cmdlets.

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

According to your error, you could not use `Select-AzureSubscription -Default "XXXYYYZZZ"`. `Default` could not add parameters. More information please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/select-azuresubscription?view=azuresmps-3.7.0#examples).

Try to use the following cmdlets.

```
Get-AzureSubscription

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName <YourSubscriptionName> -Default
```

Comment: This works perfect. You are correct Since these are classic machines, I shuold not use Rm cmdlets. Switching to Select-AzureSubscription did the trick. Thank you very much